# Exposing additional properties on entities in WCF Data Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I feel I may be missing something critical (*or just simple*) here, however I can't get this working.

---

Given I have created an ASP.NET (.NET 4.0) web application project, in which I host a WCF Data Service.
I have generated an EF 5.0 model of POCO entities from an existing database, and as usual the entity classes are `partial`.

I figure,

> Gee, I'll "extend" these partial classes to expose additional (*non-persisted, calculated*) properties<sup>*</sup> in the data service.

** For the sake of brevity, let's assume a `Person` entity, to which I want to add a `FullName` property which concatenates `FirstName` and `LastName`.*

Anyway, I go about my business continuing the `partial` class (*in the same namespace of course*)

```
public partial class Person {
    public string FullName {
        get { return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName; }
    }
}
```

However, when I query a `Person` entity in the service, no `FullName`. When I query the service's `$metadata`, no definition of `FullName`.

What (*if anything*) needs to be done to support this?

---

**Notes**

- All entities are visible via `config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);`
- I've tried decorating with various attributes with no success, including `EdmScalarPropertyAttribute` and `DataMemberAttribute` on the property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless it changed in .NET 4.5 (I haven't looked) I don't think that can work. `DataService<T>` is extremely limited. It doesn't even support all EF features. Data services themselves are quite flexible, and [you can define an entirely custom service which returns anything you want](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/04/creating-a-data-service-provider-part-1-intro.aspx). But then you don't get the "automatic" mapping of your EF context.

So you unfortunately have to choose between "easy but limited" and "difficult but flexible" with almost nothing in between.

Comment: I see. I didn't think this was something that the data service itself would be concerned with; rather, that EF was giving me guff under the hood somewhere. I thought the data service was predominantly just mapping URIs/methods to entities and their members. What difference is there between modifying the entity definition manually over regenerating it from an modified schema?

Comment: Your extension property is totally unknown to the EF model. The `DataService<T>` derives its typing info from the EF model. So only properties which are actually part of your EF model will ever show up.

Comment: Got it; I've been exploring some of the features offered in newer versions of WCF DS, as well as custom service definition. Perhaps somewhere down the line a balance between ease of implementation and flexibility will surface.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way, by using POCOs, as explained in this excellent post: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/514598/Understanding-OData-v3-and-WCF-Data-Services-5-x
(go to the Creating a WCF Data Service with POCOs section)

Basically it's describing this:

You can decorate your POCO entities with these attributes:

```
[DataServiceEntity]
[DataServiceKey("Id")]
public class MyClass
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a class that exposes static IQueryable<> members of your entities collections:

```
public class MyClassesDataSource
{

    public static IQueryable<MyClass>
    {
         get
         {
             ... // You can access your EF context here
         }
    }
}
```

Finally, instead of creating your service by deriving from `DataService<YouObjectContext>`, derive it from `DataService<MyClassesDataSource>`

Now I'm trying to figure out what's the best way of handling the EF context within that data source :)